# Access contents of a named Excel range which does not refer to a cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, named

I have created a named range, say "TestRange" in Excel which contains a formula in the "Refers to" box.  It could be as simple as multiplying 2 cells together eg Refers to:=Sheet1!G25*Sheet1!G26.  I have also tried this for storing a constant and I assume the solution to the issue is the same in that case as well.  The idea is for the result not to be in a cell in the worksheet making it easier to hide from the user but nevertheless accessible in the worksheet and VBA.

So far so good, I can access that value in the worksheet so I know the formula is OK but what I also want is to use that value in VBA.

Using

`SomeValue=Range("TestRange").Value`

does not work although it does work if the formula is in the worksheet and the "Refers to:" part is the cell containing the formula.  I have also tried to use

`Somevalue=ThisWorkbook.Names("TestRange").RefersTo`

without success.  What should I be doing or is it not possible?

Comment: Is the scope of the named Range set to Workbook? If so, I'd expect `SomeValue=Range("TestRange").Value` to work.

Otherwise, try: `SomeValue=ThisWorkBook.Sheet1.Range("TestRange").Value`, where Sheet1 is the **(Name)** of the sheet, which you can see/change in the properties of the sheet when selected in the VBA editor.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Evaluate` which will calculate the `RefersTo` like if in a cell.

`Somevalue=Evaluate(ThisWorkbook.Names("TestRange").RefersTo)`